# Reference request for general Hurwitz spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $G$ be a fixed finite group. I'm interested in the structure of the set  $\mathcal{H}_{r,g,h,G}$ of tuples $(C,f,\delta)$, where $C$ is a smooth projective genus $g\geq 2$ curve, $\delta:G\to\mbox{Aut}(C)$ is an injective group homomorphism, $f:C\to C'$ is a finite Galois morphism with $r$ ramification points and Galois group $\delta(G)$, and $C'$ is a smooth projective curve of genus $h\geq 1$. When $h=0$, then this is just the usual Hurwitz scheme (or at least one of the usual ones) of Galois morphisms to $\mathbb{P}^1$ with fixed Galois group, and can be seen as the coarse moduli scheme of a certain functor (basically the above construction but relativized).

However, it seems to me that for $h>0$, not much is known. I have seen certain functors defined but where the $C'$ above is a fixed curve, not one that moves. I, on the other hand, am interested in not fixing the $C'$. Is there any literature on this? Can this set be seen as a coarse moduli scheme for a functor?

Comment: Is $C'$ the quotient of $C$ by the action of $G$? If not, what's the connection between $G,\delta$ and $f$?

Comment: Sorry, yes! I will edit it right away.

Comment: If you do not fix $C'$, then how do you define the classical Hurwitz schemes where $C'$ is a smooth, projective genus $0$ curve?  Anyway, for topological properties, it will not make much difference whether or not you fix $C'$.  Some of the modern references are by Fulton, particularly in positive characteristic.  The generalization to arbitrary $C'$ of Hurwitz's irreducibility theorem (in characteristic 0) has been "rediscovered" many times, perhaps first in the thesis of Richard Hamilton, but then also by Gabai-Kazez and others (at one time, Graber, Harris, and I needed this as well).

Comment: Dear Jason, thanks for your comment. I think you're right, that the construction should be analogous to the classical case. I will take a look at the papers you describe.

Comment: I just saw that what I am calling "Hurwitz's irreducibility theorem" is actually due jointly to L"uroth, Clebsch, and Hurwitz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from Jason Starr's excellent references in the comments above, I also found

```
José Bertin, Compactification des schémas de Hurwitz, C.R. Acad. Sci. Paris I, vol. 322 (1996), 1063-1066.
```

and

```
S. Wewers, Construction of Hurwitz spaces, Dissertation, Universität Essen, 1998.
```

that basically show that the space parametrizing $G$-covers with specified genus of the quotient and specified ramification type (i.e. the conjugacy classes of the stabilizers of the action) has a natural structure of quasi-projective variety. Since the ramification type data is finite, then this shows that the space I ask about above also has the structure of a quasi-projective variety.